# ${workspaceRoot}/../../ breaks on windows since the workspaceRoot resolves with backspaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

A simple task runner for python executable breaks if we reference ${workspaceRoot}/../venv/python.exe since the variable resolves with back slashes. Is there a way to keep the path resolution to "/" or make OS specific tasks.